# Network adapter not showing up in wifislax

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, virtualbox, vmware

my network adapter `realtek rtl8188ftv wireless lan 802.11n usb 2.0 network adapter`

It does not appear when I connect it to wifislax and type `ifconfig` or `iwconfig`

it only appears when I type `lsusb`

I tried everything in `vmware` and `virtualbox` but it didn't work

Problem from my perspective: my network adapter is connected to wifislax but it needs a driver to tell wifislax that it is a network adapter

Whatever the problem, I want a solution

Comment: This question is most unclear. What do VMware and VBOX have to do with this? Are you using virtual machines?  In which case, you will not see the actual adapter inside the virtual machine.

Comment: I use vmware and I have a problem with my external network adapter (usb)

Comment: You need to look up the USB manufacturer and ask for a driver for it . Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the article
[Here’s how to Enable Realtek RTL8188FTV Wi-Fi adapter on Linux (Ubuntu)](https://jilaxzone.com/2022/09/06/heres-how-to-enable-realtek-rtl8188ftv-wi-fi-adapter-on-linux-ubuntu-beginner-friendly-guide/).

In a nutshell:

- Open Terminal
- Ensure the WiFi adapter is there with prefix such as "wlx" :
  `ip a` or `lsusb`
- Updates your Linux packages to the latest:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt upgrade
  sudo apt install net-tools
  ```
- Add Kelebek repository:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/kablosuz
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Install the Realtek RTL8188FTV WiFi adapter:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install rtl8188fu-dkms
  sudo apt purge rtl8188fu-dkms     (optional)
  ```
- Change the Realtek RTL8188FTV WiFi adapter driver config:

  ```
  echo "options rtl8188fu rtw_ips_mode=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188fu.conf
  sudo modprobe -rv rtl8188fu && sudo modprobe -v rtl8188fu
  ```
- Reboot
- Connect to your Wi-Fi : *Grid button > Settings > Wi-Fi*,
  turn ON the Wi-Fi (if required),
  then select the network and key in the password.

More details can be found in the linked article.

Comment: Well, I don't know if the answer is correct or not, because I think `apt` is not available in wifislax (I can't run `apt` command)

Comment: I think that for wfislax it is `slapt-get`, and you may also have `gslapt` and `slpkg` in case the packages are not in `slapt-get`. (Spanish [link](https://foro.seguridadwireless.net/live-wifislax/por-que-no-funciona-apt-get-como-instalo-programas-por-mi-cuenta-en-wifislax/) via Google Translate).